# Subnormal series of maximal finite length

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This question is from textbook Algebra by Thomas Hungerford.

> Prove that a composition series of a group is a subnormal series of maximal (finite) length.

The Composition series is a subnormal series such that   $ G =G_0 > G_1 > \cdots> G_n =\langle e\rangle$ such that each $G_i /G_{i+1}$ is simple.

Now, it is a subnormal series so I already know that $G_{i+1} $ is normal in $G_i$ .$G_i /G_{i+1}$ being simple means only normal proper subgroup is identity.

But I am not able to use it in proving what is not required. Please help.

Comment: There is a correspondence between the (normal) subgroups of $G_i/G_{i+1}$ and the (normal) subgroups of $G_i$ containing $G_{i+1}$ (this is sometimes called the correspondence theorem). Hence, in your situation you cannot add a new term between $G_i$ and $G_{i+1}$. To show that the length of a series is maximal among all such subnormal series, you probably need the Jordan-Hölder theorem.

Comment: I  can't see any question here.

Comment: @DerekHolt I edit it. I am sorry